# Не обнаруживаются созданные файлы в дереве проекта Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Возникла проблема по созданию проекта Qt. Файлы расширения .cpp и .h не отображаются, при этом являются созданными и хранятся в папке с проектом.

[image: Главное окно Qt Creator и дерево проекта]

Также прикладываю экранный снимок раздела настроек сборки:

[image: Параметры сборки и запуска]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все файлы, участвующие в сборке проекта, должны быть прописаны в .pro-файле. Их можно прописать там вручную следующим образом:

```
SOURCES += \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/Other_File.cpp
HEADERS += \
    inc/main.h \
    inc/Other_File.h
```

Либо можно в дереве проекта с левой стороны среды разработки нажать правой кнопкой на корневой элемент (или на любой другой, если файл нужно добавить не в корень), и выбрать пункт "Добавить существующие файлы". Если вы хотите создать новый файл, следует выбрать пункт "Добавить новый". После выполнения этих манипуляций файлы появятся в вашем .pro-файле и будут доступны компилятору.